# how to make row text going center

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i want to ask how to make the text going center.
i have row that contain 2 text.
below is my code.

```
Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Great",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 44.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontFamily: "Berlin"),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Ocean",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontSize: 44.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontFamily: "Berlin"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

and output from that code is going like this.

how to make that row going center?

Comment: Use [MainAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html) property in Row. 
`MainAxisAlignment.center`

Comment: remove centre and 
Use MainAxisAlignment property in Row. MainAxisAlignment.center

Comment: thank you guys, really thank you. it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this but first, I would like to refactor your code. You are using `Padding` inside a `Container` widget, which is totally unnecessary as `Container` widget already has a property called `padding`. So, you should remove the `Padding` widget.

Also, you have used `Center` widget inside `Container` which is also unnecessary as `Container` has `alignment` property which you can use to center align child widgets (`Alignment.center`).

Lastly, in order to center align children widgets in a `Row` widget, there is `mainAxisAlignment` & `crossAxisAlignment` properties which you can use to align widgets.

Setting `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.center` will center all of your children widgets.

Also, you have used two different `Text` widgets to create different styled `Text` widgets, which you can do with a single `RichText` widget.

[image]
Your final code should look like this:

```
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 44.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              fontFamily: "Berlin"),
          text: "Great",
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Ocean',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontSize: 44.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontFamily: "Berlin"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```